# received from a messaging app in Hong Kong, I would like to ask for an English explanation of the title

Tags: cantonese

[image]

obstacle: the song of 老餅, how to interpret this word in English

Comment: Just the Title? Well, from the drift of the Chinese Limerick, a paraphrase translation would be "Lamentations of an Old Fart", though it is worded literally as "Song of an Old Biscuit" Chinese people like euphemisms in everything.

Comment: [老餅](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/290483293.html) 粤语说老饼是指年纪大的人(多指中年以上的男人) In Cantonese, Laobing (old  cake) means old people (mostly refer to middle-aged or older men)

Comment: It is a very interesting poem about aging. Someone may be able to translate and share it with everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [老餅](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/290483293.html) 粤语说老饼是指年纪大的人(多指中年以上的男人)

> In Cantonese, Laobing (old cake) means old people (mostly refer to middle-aged or older men)

老餅之歌 (song of old guys)

一晚通宵 唔捱得 (can't endure all nigher for one night) -- *older men can't go without sleep for long hours*

兩腳遠啲 唔行得 (two feet can't walk for a longer distance) -- *older men have weaker legs*

三粒藥丸 唔少得 (can't go without three pills) --  *old men need to take medicine*

四篤夜尿 唔忍得 (can't resist the need to go pee four times a night)

五更醒咗 唔瞓得 (wake up at 2:00 am, can't go back to sleep)

六種骨痛 唔郁得 (have six kinds of bone pain, can't move)

七種凍品 唔受得 (can't stand seven types of cold serving food or drink)

八卦小氣 唔激得 (gossipy and stingy, quick to get angry) - *typical stereotype of grumpy old man*

狗屎垃圾 唔捨得 (can't bear to part with useless junks) -- *狗(dog) sounds the same as 九(nine) -- 狗屎垃圾 (dog shit and garbage) means "useless junks"*

十分鐘後 唔記得 (forget ten minutes later) -- *old men have poor memory*